¿Como logro hacer que mi zona horaria en PHP agarre la hora del sistema operativo?
Tengo un pequeño detalle con la zona horaria de México,agregue date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");  hasta ahi esta bien, pero en mi país México en las zonas fronterizas el cambio de horario no lo quitaron sigue igual, 9:17 am zona centro de México y 10:17 zona frontera, y entro otras zonas varían el horario como Chihuahua México, estoy implementado detalles de compras con PayPal cuando un cliente termine su compra digamos si el vive en Tijuana México la fecha y hora le sale una hora menos tal como esta en el timezone.
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
echo "<p> Fecha: ". date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "</p>";


¿Qué te devuelve timezone_version_get()?.

Me devuelve esto 2022.6

Tu versión ya incluye las nuevas zonas, no hay necesidad de actualizar. ¿Cómo sabes que un cliente vive en Tijuana?.

@Sal es un decir porque la tienda en online pueden acceder en cualquier parte de la república Mexicana y en algunos estados no tienen la misma hora que en la CDMX

Utiliza https://worldtimeapi.org/ y entonces es imposible fallar.

Para que PHP use la hora del sistema operativo automáticamente, elimina date_default_timezone_set() y configura la zona horaria en php.ini con date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City".
Además, asegúrate de que el sistema operativo tenga configurada correctamente la zona horaria.
Para obtener la hora correcta en el lado del cliente (es decir, según la zona horaria del usuario), debes usar JavaScript, ya que PHP solo maneja la hora en el servidor.
